# How can I make an image grow in height based on the length of text?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, height

The image of an owl is right next to a block of text. I want the owl to have the height of the text so there's no awkward space underneath it. How should I approach this problem?

http://lectorbookclub.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with: `height:100%`.

Comment: thanks NoName! I was trying that and it didn't work until I used my own img tag...WordPress's default img tag was holding me back.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh had to get out of using the WordPress img src default. AFter, I had more freedom to change the image size.